# data manipulation - splitting and shaping one data frame by matching values to another data frame

Tags: r, string, split

I have two data frames given below:

df1

```
ob         optcode
1 flora   gg,bb,cc, pb
2 alexa    tt,dd, pb
3 dixon      gg, cc
```

df2

```
obname   type
1     gg orange
2     bb  apple
3     cc  nooption     
4     tt  grape
5     pb  nooption     
6     dd  melon
```

What I am looking at doing is to split the 'optcode' column in df1 using something like cSplit or strsplit function but the values should go into their corresponding columns as described in df2. So for row-1 in df1, flora has three values under optcode of gg,bb,cc. These values should be split such that  gg is matched with the type in df2, the column name then becomes the type and 'gg' goes as a value. Same for the rest. The result should be:

df3

```
 ob        nooption    orange apple grape  melon
1 flora      cc, pb     gg     bb    none   none
2 alexa      pb        none   none    tt     dd
3 dixon      cc        gg   none   none   none
```

Another thing to note is that if there is no type for an optcode in df2 then for the remaining types there should be an empty string or NA or none is displayed. There should be as many columns as there are types plus an additional column of options where a value is populated if there is no type associated with that value. Hope the explanation makes sense.

I have tried cSplit on df1 and it is working successfully but the desired result is not acheived as more manual processing is required afterwards.

Looking forward to hearing suggestions and ways to accomplish the above.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not share the code you've already written so we can help with the last step rather than making us start from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

We can do this with `data.table` and `splitstackshape`.  Using `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`, we split the 'optcode' by the delimiter `,` to `long` format, then `join` `on` the 'optcode' with the 'obname' from the second dataset ('df2'), create a 'options' column with the values from 'optcode' where the 'type' is blank (`""` - we specify that as `i`).  Using `dcast`, convert the 'long' to 'wide' format.

```
library(data.table)
d1 <- dcast(
        cSplit(df1, "optcode", ",", "long")[
           df2, on = c("optcode" ="obname")
             ][type == "", options := optcode], 
              ob + options ~type, value.var = "optcode")
```

Grouped by 'ob', we remove the NA elements of each row and assign (`:=`) the additional column 'V1' to NULL.

```
d1[, lapply(.SD, na.omit) , ob][, V1 := NULL][]
#      ob options apple grape melon orange
#1: alexa      NA    NA    tt    dd     NA
#2: dixon      pb    NA    NA    NA     NA
#3: flora      cc    bb    NA    NA     gg
```

#### data

```
df1 <-  structure(list(ob = c("flora", "alexa", "dixon"), optcode = c("gg,bb,cc", 
"tt,dd", "pb")), .Names = c("ob", "optcode"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))

df2 <- structure(list(obname = c("gg", "bb", "cc", "tt", "pb", "dd"), 
 type = c("orange", "apple", "", "grape", "", "melon")), .Names = c("obname", 
 "type"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6"))
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun. How would you change the code if instead of missing/empty values there is a value let's say "none". shall I take this "[type == "", options := optcode]" part of the code out then?

Comment: @syebill I would assume that would work considering that 'type' is `character` class.

Comment: Can you have a look at it again. will appreciate your help.

Comment: @syebill I have a doubt.  Shouldn't `dixon` be 'cc' in the output for 'nooption' column

Comment: You are correct. Rectified. Thanks! any thoughts on what needs changing in your code?

Comment: @syebill Try `df3 <- cSplit(df1, "optcode", ",", "long")[df2, on = .(optcode = obname)][, .(optcode = paste(unique(optcode), collapse=", ")), .(ob, type)][type=="nooption", nooption := optcode][];  dcast(unique(df3, by = c("type", "optcode")), ob+ nooption ~type, value.var="optcode")[,lapply(.SD, na.omit) , ob]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyr`/`dplyr` approach. IMO the below approach is pretty straightforward, the only trick was taking care of the missing values (i.e. the `NA`'s) after merging `df1` and `df2`.  This is done by replacing all missing entries in type with `"options"` and then removing all missing entries of obname.

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df2[df2$type=="", "type"] = NA #replacing blanks with NA, we need for merger later

df1 %>% 
  separate(optcode, into = paste0("opt", seq(1, max(str_count(.$optcode, ",")) + 1)), sep=",") %>% #the code passed to the into argument is a bit overkill, however, it generalizes to any number of elements contained in optcode
  gather(key, obname, -ob) %>%
  left_join(df2) %>%
  select(-key) %>%
  mutate(type = ifelse(is.na(type), "options", type)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(obname)) %>%
  spread(type,obname)
```